# How to create composed key in Workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, workbench

I have table `OrdersPhoto` with two foreign keys: `Order_Id` and `Photo_Id`:

How to create a composed key based on them as: `Order_Id__Photo_Id` using Workbench? Should it be additional field, or just set up primary key for each?

[image]

Comment: So, is it enough to set up two foreign keys as primary keys to make compose key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the PK you can create the composite key by simply activating the checkboxes for all columns participating in that key. For all others (and alternatively also for the PK) use the index tab in the table editor.

[image]]

Use the index details list to add and remove columns for a key. You can indicate the column order here too. Just change the number in the `#` column.